# Configure system default python to use anaconda's packages

Tags: python, python-3.4, anaconda

I have to keep using the `system's default` python3.4 on a centos server. I'm wondering if there is any way to configure system's python using anaconda's python packages:P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`update-alternatives` will do this trick. Simply remember switching to Py3.4 when you need and switching it back after you finished!